# WHMCS - Editing purchased theme by overriding specific files

Tags: whmcs, custom-theme

I want to customize the purchased WHMCS theme but I don't want to loose the changes when the theme is updated.
So, is there a way to create a child type of theme just like we do on Wordpress. If not, please advice the best method to do it in WHMCS.

Answer (score 0):

WHMCS doesn't support clientarea template files overriding as in WP.

Use `git` to follow changes in the original purchased template, as described in [Six template page](https://github.com/WHMCS/templates-six#command-line-usage)